# How to route back to original interface

Tags: networking, proxy, routes, iptables

Sorry, my networking skills are subpar,

I have a scenario where I have 2 different networks and have 2 servers in those networks, server A is in network A, server B in network B

When someone tries to connect to an external server (over internet), we have a virtual interface configured between A & B (IPIP tunnel)

1)
If I try to netcat/telnet external server (x.x.100.3), I have a route on serverA that routes to my virtual inteface (tunnel1)

2) tunnel1 sends packets over IPIP tunnel to its peer "tunnel2"

3) I need to route any requests to x.x.100.3 over to another internet-facing p1p1 interface

4) serverB sends packets to external serverC over p1p1 interface (I tested running *tcpdump -i p1p1* and can see the packets going out

5) reply from C comes back to p1p1

If I do the same netcat cmd from B, I get connected. Yet from A, I get a timeout.

SO my question is, how do I configure this setup so the user who initiates Netcat on server A, gets the reply from server C? Right now the connection stops at server B (p1p1) because the packet header is changing after the Route on B.

I tried playing with iproute2 table rules but cannot get it to work. I basically need to use Server B as a "proxy" network server for any requests going to external server C.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

figured out the problem, I didnt have a gateway route in place. This was preventing the back-forth flow of packets.

heres the write up how to setup IPIP tunnel between 2 networks,

https://sites.google.com/site/mrxpalmeiras/linux/create-ipip-tunnel-between-networks